# Issues with arcpy.sa.Reclassify

Tags: arcpy, reclassify

I have a raster file with classifcation codes, and want to reclassify valid codes to 1, and all others to 'NoData'.

```
RMAP2 = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[3.2, 1],
                             [4.1, 1],
                             [4.2, 1]])

LCA = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(LCA, "LCCODE_USE", RMAP2, "NODATA")
```

The output however only contains the values 0 and 127, with the 0 value coinciding with just one of the missing values.

Any idea what the hell is going on?

Comment: I wouldn't trust a "3.2" in Python to translate, bit-by-bit, to the *single precision* float ArcGIS actually stores in that raster. That's asking too much.  At a minimum you should be reclassifying narrow *ranges* of values, such as (3.15,3.25)-->1, (4.05,4.15)-->1, etc. But before even trying this, you ought to test your code with a simple, small, *integer* raster just to make sure you have correctly interpreted the syntax. Can you at least verify for us that such a test works and gets the right result?

Comment: I tried it on an integer raster, and yes it worked fine, so I floating point error makes sense. won't be able to test it out till Thursday though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the [Reclass by Table (Spatial Analyst) geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/) instead of the plain [Reclassify (Spatial Analyst) geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclassify/009z000000sr000000/). The former takes a Table View containing the ranges of values to be reclassified; the latter utilizes the arcpy.sa.RemapValue Python objects to define the ranges of values to be reclassified.

So I think your code should be:

```
RMAP2 = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[3.2, 1],
                             [4.1, 1],
                             [4.2, 1]])

LCA = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(LCA, "LCCODE_USE", RMAP2, "NODATA")
```

I can't test this for sure, since I don't have Spatial Analyst on the machine I'm using right now.

Comment: Crud, sorry, I meant to edit that, I had actually been using Reclassify, but started rewriting it to Reclass by table before giving up and asking here.

Comment: So what's up above now is the actually code I was using.